# AWS lambda event parameters: When does Records hold multiple items in it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-net

I have an infrastructure such as this: `S3` -> `SQS` -> `Lambda`. When a file is dropped to S3, it puts the event into an SQS queue, which then is consumed by a lambda function.

Lambda is written in .net core. In lambda handlers parameter, I receive an `SQSEvent` and within its body, an `S3Event` that is serialized to Json.

The class structures are roughly as below. They are straight from the AWS .net SDK.

```
class SQSEvent
{
    public List<SQSMessage> Records;
    ...
}

class SQSMessage
{
    public string Body; // json serialized S3Event is put into here
    ...
}

class S3Event
{
    public List<S3EventNotification> Records;
    ...
}
```

The part I'm curious about is that, both `SQSEvent` and `S3Event` have a list of records. In my experiments, I always received a single item in those lists. Is it known under which circumstances any of these `Records` list will contain multiple items in it? I failed to find a document stating about this behaviour.

Comment: I've often wondered this myself. I always code it to handle multiple records, but I've only seen single records come through.

Answer (score 3):

If many records are generated in a very short amount of time, for example if many S3 files were uploaded simultaneously, then Amazon may send a list of records in a single event.

Comment: I don't think that's true.  This is just a common format used by a number of different services.  Lambda@Edge trigger events from CloudFront use [the exact same outer structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html) and will never present anything other than 1 member of `event.Records`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it is definitely true of the SQS integration, which is one of the event types listed in the question. You will definitely get multiple records from SQS unless you explicitly configure it to only send one message to Lambda at a time. I believe Amazon built all these data structures in such a way that they can queue messages up in case something happens where they can't invoke the Lambda function for some time, after which point they may send more than one message in a single event in order to clear out the queue quickly.

Comment: that's true on SQS >> Lambda integration, but for S3 events... here's what I suspect led me to my conclusion several years ago: *"Currently, all S3 event notifications have a single event per notification message. We might include multiple records as we add new event types in the future. This is also a message format that is shared across other AWS services, and other services can include multiple records."* https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=592080&#592080

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that's the answer I was looking for. Thank you. Honestly, my application cares more about the s3event than the sqsevent, so your finding is pretty useful to me. You might wanna put together an answer so I can accept it.